# What is the best way to learn about Modular Forms?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, learning-roadmap

I am a senior Mathematics Major, and I am interesting in learning about Modular Forms. I have a layman's general sense of what they are but I was wondering if there is a lecture(I am willing to pay) or a book that explains Modular forms in Layman terms to in mathematical terms. I understand it's not the easiest topic in the world so I was hoping I can have it be explained in Layman's terms and then built from there.  Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "A First Course in Modular Forms" Diamond and Shurman. http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387232294

Comment: Try the second half of Serre's Course in Arithmetic.

Comment: I recommend Fearless Symmetry by Ash and Gross.:

Comment: I like Sarnak's book.

Comment: The first chapter of "1-2-3 of modular forms", written by Don Zagier, may be a good source that talks both about what the objects are, and how they are useful.

Comment: @Lucia : As an undergrad, I attempted to read Serre to learn about modular forms. I could follow the proofs, but felt that I gained no understanding of why anyone would be interested in them. IMO, after you already understand something about modular forms, then it's worth going back to Serre for an elegant and efficient presentation of the basic facts, but I don't recommend Serre as a first introduction to modular forms.

Comment: Besides the books already suggested I would recommend to someone who never studied the subject before: Modular forms, a computational approach (by William Stein). Serre's book is algo very good.

Comment: For clarification: is the question really about layman's terms, or could the discussion at least assume a solid undergrad background and for sure some complex analysis?

Comment: Is this question not more suited for MSE?  (Particularly if it is for everyman)